# StreamWriter.WriteLine is including an extra \r

Tags: c#, .net, stream, streamwriter

I have some code like this:

```
var ms = new MemoryStream();
var sw = new StreamWriter(ms);

foreach(/* some iteration */)
{
    sw.WriteLine("Some string");
}

sw.Flush();
ms.Position = 0;

// Return the stream in Asp.Net MVC, FileResult.
```

With a hexadecimal reader I get these values for each end of string:

```
... 0x0d 0x0d 0x0a
// in escape chars:
... \r\r\n
```

But I was expecting some like `"\r\n"`. Why the extra `"\r"`? How can I fix that? I'm using UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: Just a clue , Can you check your data , it might have an additional **\r**

Comment: Voting to close because your example [does not reproduce the problem](https://dotnetfiddle.net/caHxVA) at all. Whatever your problem is, it is not in the code you have provided. Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that generates the extra `\r`s

Comment: Does every string have the extra \r or only some strings.

Comment: I check my data, don't have an additional \r. Because of the sugestion of voting to close I create another question that specify better the problem, and have some updates about what check it out: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29705703/1233788