# StreamWriter add an extra \r in the end of the line

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, iis, streamwriter

I created a class with the responsibility to generate a text file where each line represents the information of an object of 'MyDataClass' class. Below is a simplification of my code:

```
public class Generator
{
    private readonly Stream _stream;
    private readonly StreamWriter _streamWriter;
    private readonly List<MyDataClass> _items;

    public Generator(Stream stream)
    {
        _stream = stream;
        _streamWriter = new StreamWriter(_stream, Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1"));
    }

    public void Generate()
    {
        foreach (var item in _items)
        {
            var line = AnotherClass.GetLineFrom(item);

            _streamWriter.WriteLine(line);
        }

        _streamWriter.Flush();
        _stream.Position = 0;
    }
}
```

And I call this class like this:

```
using (var file = new FileStream("name", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
{
    new Generator(file).Generate();
}
```

When I run the application on visual studio (I test with run (Ctrl+F5), debug (F5), with debug and release mode) all goes according to the plan. But I publish the application in a IIS server and now StreamWriter class put an extra \r before the end of the line.

Check it out the hexadecimal reading of both generated files:

Running in Visual Studio:
http://www.jonataspiazzi.xpg.com.br/hex_vs.bmp

Running in IIS:
http://www.jonataspiazzi.xpg.com.br/hex_iis.bmp

**Some things I already checked:**

> Write the `line` variable (in `var line = AnotherClass.GetLineFrom(item);`) in a log to see if an extra '\r' is uncluded by the class `AnotherClass`.

Didn't result in nothing, the last char in `line` is a regular char like expected (in example above is a space).

> Write another code to see if the problem is general for all IIS StreamWriter instances.

I tried this:

```
var ms = new MemoryStream();
var sw = new StreamWriter(ms, Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1"));

sw.WriteLine("Test");
sw.WriteLine("Of");
sw.WriteLine("Lines");

sw.Flush();
ms.Position = 0;
```

In this case the code works well for both visual studio and IIS.

I'm in this for 3 days, I already try everything my brain can think. Did anyone have any clue for what I can try?

**UPDATE**

Get weirder! I try to replace the line `_streamWriter.WriteLine(line);` with:

```
_streamWriter.Write(linhaTexto + Environment.NewLine);
```

And even worse:

```
_streamWriter.Write(linhaTexto + "\r\n");
```

Both keep generating the extra `\r` character.

I try replace with this:

```
_streamWriter.Write(linhaTexto + "#\r\n#");
```

And get:

http://www.jonataspiazzi.xpg.com.br/hex_sharp.bmp

Comment: What happen if you try to remove the encoding?

Comment: The error remains. I tried without encoding, with `Defaul`, with `UTF8` and with `"ISO-8859-15"`. All get me the same result.

Comment: Is it possible that the extra \r is added during a File Transfer from the server?

Comment: The file is save in a folder and I'm getting it with FTP.

Comment: Oh.. that could be your issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that the extra \r is added during FTP (maybe try a binary transfer)

Like [here](https://superuser.com/questions/165539/winscp-screws-up-line-breaks-in-files-how-do-avoid)

I've tested the code and the extra /r is not due to the code in the current question

Comment: Tears of joy rolling in my face friend!

Answer (score 6):

According to MSDN, WriteLine

> Writes data followed by a line terminator to the text string or stream.

your last line should be

```
 _streamWriter.Write(line);
```

Put it outside of your loop and change your loop so it doesn't manage the last line.

Comment: This may be work if my problem was only in last line. But the problem occurs in all line endings of the file.

Comment: And if you change all your writeLine for write?

Comment: My point is it seems like for some reasons an extra line is added. I was wondering if Write alone would add an extra line. Not the solution, just some verification.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. Environment.NewLine and WriteLine gave me extra \r character. But this below worked for me:

```
StringBuilder sbFileContent = new StringBuilder();
sbFileContent.Append(line);
sbFileContent.Append("\n");
streamWriter.Write(sbFileContent.ToString());
```

Comment: This helped me with my problem, but I had to use .Append(Environment.NewLine) instead of .Append("\n")

Comment: Environment.NewLine is safer since it returns newline for the platform your code is running.

Answer (score 0):

I just now had a similar problem where the code below **would randomly insert blank lines** in the output file (outFile)

```
using (StreamWriter outFile = new StreamWriter(outFilePath, true)) {
     foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(logPath)) {
            string concatLine = parse(line, out bool shouldWrite);
            if (shouldWrite) {
              outFile.WriteLine(concatLine);       
            }     
      }   
}
```

Using Antar's idea I changed my parse function so that it returned a line with Environment.NewLine appended, ie

```
return myStringBuilder.Append(Environment.NewLine).ToString();
```

and then in the foreach loop above, changed the

```
outFile.WriteLine(concatLine);
```

to

```
outFile.Write(concatLine);
```

and now it writes the file without a bunch of random new lines inserted.  However, I still have absolutely no idea why I should have to do this.